# My app got rejected because below issue in play store

Tags: android

[image]

can anyone help me with what I am doing mistakes because of the above reason my app got rejected I have already updated the test user I am trying to live my app close to the testing mode in beta but my app got rejected I have followed everything we don't know what information we need to fill and where . please help me .

Comment: The screenshot perfectly tells you what to do

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the access so that google could properly test your app. In google Play Console go to your project. Go to App Content > App access
[image]

Then you need to add Instructions.
[image]

Then add Login information. Make sure that the username and password for the test user is correct and aren't restricted somehow (e.g location locked). The test user should also have all permission so that all of the features of the app can be tested.
[image]

Then submit these instruction.

Comment: Thanks @Moiz but we don't have any login page we have Phone number with OTP in that case what we need enter ?

Comment: @MARSH make a test phone number in app which you enter and the OTP is skipped. Instead of Login information just enter the test phone number in the fields.